# Apple Push Notification and Google Cloud Messaging Configuration

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Hi I'm about to study Push Notification for IOS and Google Cloud Messaging android. I have my own website, host, server, database. How should I start? Should I build my own push server or use other push server and what language should use on server side? any document or reference should be much appreciate, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I Think you shroud have first knowledge of APN(Apple Push Notification). and start learning to send notification with APN. java is the best language to use as backend.

learn more for APn.
http://jigneshkanjariya.blogspot.in/2015/12/apple-push-notification-in-java.html

learn more for GCM
http://jigneshkanjariya.blogspot.in/2015/12/gcm-in-java.html

Comment: Thanks for yrs help. Do u have any demo source code or tutorial so that we can have better understanding?

Comment: Yes .I have been Share artical on my blog for Apple Push Notification with Java.This Link Give you A better Idea About Notification Sending. Please View  it.    .http://jigneshkanjariya.blogspot.in/2015/12/apple-push-notification-in-java.html